# show Checkbox Only if it is checked

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to show checkbox if it is checked, my Razor is the following

```
@foreach (var I in Model)
{
 <tr id="row_@I._id">
  <td class="v-align-top" id="Checkboxcard">
   <div class="checkbox text-center" id="checkboxDIV">
     <input type="checkbox" value="@I._id" id="checkbox_@I._id)">
      <label for="checkbox_@I._id"></label>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
}
```

My stylesheet has this

```
 #checkboxDIV {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #Checkboxcard:hover #checkboxDIV {
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

When I move my mouse over the `#Checkboxcard` - It shows the checkbox

But I want the checkbox to stay VISIBLE if it is checked.

Is it possible? Any suggestions, please.

Cheers

Comment: might want to use `:checked` ?

Comment: how can you check a hidden checkbox? hovering on a hidden check box is not user friendly

Comment: You run into multiple problems with your code, both `checkboxDIV` and `Checkboxcard` would be duplicated id's inside your loop, ID should be unique at all times.

Comment: @aliusman check my answer below

Comment: I think he wants the outer div to remain visible when the inner checkbox is checked. A pure CSS solution won't work for that as you can't travel up the chain. See my JavaScript-based solution (although as pointed out above, OP will need to change out that CheckboxDIV id to a class if this has to scale to a loop).

Comment: It can be possible with pure css I have updated my answer below. @aliusman check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will watch for changes to the checkbox state and append/remove a visibility class on the wrapper (using the same style as your hover):

```
// Javascript:
    $('#checkboxDIV input').on('change',function() {
      $(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).parent.addClass('visible') : $(this).parent.removeClass('visible');
    });

// CSS    
    #Checkboxcard:hover #checkboxDIV, .visible {
      visibility: visible;
    }
```

As pointed out elsewhere though - if you're planning to output multiples of this in a loop, you'll want to change those ids to classes, as ids should be unique in HTML, you don't want multiple #checkboxDIVs on one page:

```
//html

@foreach (var I in Model)
{
 <tr id="row_@I._id">
  <td class="v-align-top Checkboxcard">
   <div class="checkbox text-center checkboxDIV">
     <input type="checkbox" value="@I._id" id="checkbox_@I._id)">
      <label for="checkbox_@I._id"></label>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
}

// Javascript:
    $('.checkboxDIV input').on('change',function() {
      $(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).parent.addClass('visible') : $(this).parent.removeClass('visible');
    });

// CSS    
    .Checkboxcard:hover .checkboxDIV, .visible {
      visibility: visible;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this with css

```css
    input[type=checkbox]{
      opacity: 0;
    }
    #Checkboxcard:hover input[type=checkbox]{
      opacity: 1;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]:checked{
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
    <div id = "Checkboxcard">
     <input type="checkbox" > Hover me<br>
    </div>
```